# Bringing foreign in-laws to Germany with new immigration law

Tags: germany

I am an EU citizen, specifically Italian, married to a Chinese citizen. We currently live in China, but we plan to move back to Europe, in Germany. We'd like our kids to grow up with their (Chinese) grandparents. I came to know that Germany introduced [a new law](https://germanyiscalling.com/new-immigration-law-in-germany-2023-updates/) that allows to bring the foreign parents of a Skilled Worker. My wife and I are both software engineers, so we fall into that category.

Since I am an EU citizen, does my wife need to prove she's a Skilled Worker? How?

We will both work as software engineer if we come back to Germany. Initially I will work, and after paper-work is done, my wife will find a job as well in the same sector. Considering the high-demand and our profile/experience, we don't expect any problems finding a decent job.

My in-laws do not depend on us financially because they have their own pension, but we live together to support each other.

Comment: Are you planning to move to Germany?  Are you German?  Are your wife's parents dependent on your wife and you?

Comment: I have updated the post with all the info you requested.

Comment: Thanks.  I suspect it would be either impossible or impractical for your wife to apply for a residence permit as a skilled worker while living in Germany with you.  As her parents are not dependent, they do not fall under the scope of article 3(1) of directive 2004/38/EC (because of the definition at Article 2(2)(d)), but they could fall under 3(2) as "members of the household."  I don't know how Germany interprets that, but the argument that they could come if your wife had weaker rights is certainly fairly persuasive to me.

Comment: I don't have time to write a proper answer today, but I'd try the free movement route as "members of the household" first (some countries, I believe, require that they were members of your household before; as I said, I don't know about Germany).  If that doesn't work then you can try to fall back on the skilled worker permit, if it's possible.

Comment: @phoog The **General administrative regulation on the Residence Act** does cover 'members of the household' of EU Citizens, but meantions only the case in the Member State of origin (not in 3rd countries). *36.2.2.9 If the person concerned is a family member of a Union citizen entitled to freedom of movement ...  this must be taken into account when exercising discretion in [§36] paragraph 2 sentence 1 [avoid exceptional hardship] ... Union citizens and family members lived in the same household **in the Member State of origin** ...*

Comment: Based on the *Freedom of Movement*, Article 3 Beneficiaries (2)(a) states: '**in the country from which they have come**, are dependants or **members of the household of the Union citizen**', a visa application (well documented) should qualify for a §36 (2) [avoiding exceptional hardship] visa. Your spouse, as a Chinese citizen, needs only a visa, as a Family Member of an EU Citizen, when arriving togeather with the EU Citizen and will recieve a **residence card** after arrival that allows any type of work.

Comment: Sorry, I think I couldn't easily follow the juridical framework you've outlined. My wife is a Chinese citizen, who will come to live in Germany as wife of an EU citizen. No problem here, since this is a typical case of family reunification with foreign spouse. But what about my wife's parents? Can they also come to live in Germany with us, given that my wife **also** qualifies as Skilled Worker, and in the law I have mentioned (2023 Skilled Immigration Act), a Skilled Worker, even from non-EU countries, can bring his/her parents?

Comment: @goodolddays It's difficult to see how she could “also” be a skilled worker, legally speaking. Either she goes down that route or she does not. It doesn't matter that your wife is doing a skilled job, is a software engineer, etc. (and it matters even less than you yourself are), what matters is holding that specific residence permit.

Comment: @goodolddays The new law doesn't change the fact that the parents must be dependent (or qualify for the hardship rule). The main changes are that the eligable group has been extended **and** that all applications can be done togeather. The parents as  **members of the household** (who are **not** dependent) criteria **only** applies to a Family Member of an EU Citizen.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Now it's all clear!